# How to use the interface of typescript with the or condition

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

I am new to the typescript. Here, I have following code which looks like ,

```
interface FirstOriginal {
  active: boolean;
  status: boolean;
}

interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  Original: FirstOriginal;
}

interface MainProduct {
  id: number;
  Name: string;
  Original: Product;
}

class MainService {
  buildproduct = memoize((products: Array<Product | MainProduct>, ismain) => {
    const group = _.groupBy(products, (bsp: Product) =>
      !ismain
        ? bsp?.Original?.active ?? undefined
        : bsp?.Original?.Original?.active ?? undefined
    );
  });
}
```

Now, here I am not able to do `bsp?.Original?.active ?? undefined : bsp?.Original?.Original?.active ?? undefined`. as I can do it for only one interface so, can any one help me with this. like,

how to use these two interface for the same class function.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use OR condition in Interface or in implementation?

Comment: IN the implementation , in products: Array<Product | MainProduct> this place.

Comment: You can use `?` to specify optional properties or parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To specify optional properties or parameters you can use `?` in front of the property/parameter name.

For eg:

```
memoize((products?: Array<Product | MainProduct>, ismain?:number) {
}
```

or

```
interface Product {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  Original?: FirstOriginal;
}
```

Another way is to use `[Partial][1]`. Partial will return all subset of a given interface.

```
memoize((products?: Array<Partial<Product | MainProduct>>, ismain?:number) {
}
```

Comment: Yeah but when I tried to do products?.Original?.Original then I can not do this as it is still taking Product as a interface and not the MainProduct . SO, I hope you got my point stuck at this,

Comment: How to use at 

const group = _.groupBy(products, (bsp: Product) =>

this line, as it has Product or MainProduct.

Comment: @GaneshKaspate you don't need to specify type for `bsp` here. It should be coming through _.groupBy via generics. If it doesn't then you can use union operator to use both interface as `bsp: Product | MainProduct `

Comment: Yes, But If I use union then it gives me the which are common in both interfaces and not in the both the places

Comment: The problem here is that, after using 

Array<Product | MainProduct>

it actually takes the union of these two interfaces and not the whole things . I am trying to get the whole key values from that interfaces. So, when I am  taking the values that time I can get only Id as Id is common in both the interfaces. hope you got my problem

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743378/how-to-use-the-conditional-interfaces-or-to-have-both-of-them-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Here it is! Interfaces do not exists on javascript. Even if you could resolve all compilation errors on execution time javascript won't be able to tell which is which. If we want to know what kind of blahblah it is we need to add javascript. It is why I created the `Imp` classes.

```js
import { groupBy, memoize } from "lodash";
import { MainOrNot } from "./tril";

interface FirstOriginal {
    active: boolean;
    status: boolean;
}

interface MainProduct {
    id: number;
    Name: string;
    Original: Product;
}

interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    Original: FirstOriginal;
}

class FirstOriginalImp implements FirstOriginal {
    active: boolean;
    status: boolean;
    public constructor(data: FirstOriginal) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

class ProductImp implements Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    Original: FirstOriginal;

    public constructor(data: Product) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

class MainProductImp implements MainProduct {
    id: number;
    Name: string;
    Original: Product;

    public constructor(data: MainProduct) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

export type MainOrNot = MainProductImp | ProductImp;

class MainService {
    buildproduct = memoize((products: Array<MainOrNot>, ismain: boolean) => {
        const group = groupBy<MainOrNot>(products, (bsp) => {
            if (bsp instanceof MainProductImp) {
                return bsp?.Original?.Original?.active ?? undefined;
            }

            if (bsp instanceof ProductImp) {
                return bsp?.Original?.active ?? undefined;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Could u please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743378/how-to-use-the-conditional-interfaces-or-to-have-both-of-them-in-typescript