# How to use the conditional interfaces or to have both of them in typescript

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, typescript

I am new to the `typescript`. Here i have two inerfaces

```
interface TestProduct {
  Id: string
  active: boolean
}

interface Product {
  Id?: string
  Name?: string
  Original: TestProduct
}

interface MainProduct {
  Id?: string
  Name?: string
  Original?: Product
}
```

Here , So, I am trying to have both the values like,

```
type Total = MainProduct | Product
```

Now, When I used this in one of my function methods ,

```
getproducts = memoize(
    (products: Array<Product>, isopen) => {
    //did some group by and got one array of object.

   const groupedValues = !isopen  ?  _.groupBy(
    products,
    (bsp: Product) => bsp?.Original?.active?.Name ?? 'Undefined'
  ) :  _.groupBy(
    buyingSessionProducts,
    (bsp: MainProduct) => bsp?.Original?.Original?.active?.Name ?? 'Undefined'
  )


   for (let value in groupedValues) {
    const sort = groupedValues[value][0].original?. //here I am able to get only Id value as it is common in both the interface. So, I am not getting either original?.active or direct original?.original?.active.
}
})
```

So, How do I get both intefaces key values over their. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have separate conditional flow for each type.

```
getproducts = memoize(
(products: Array<Product>, isopen) => {
  //did some group by and got one array of object.

  if(!isopen) {
      const groupedProductValues = _.groupBy(
        products,
        (bsp: Product) => bsp?.Original?.active?.Name ?? 'Undefined'
      )

      for (let value in groupedValues) {
          // Here value is of type Product
      }
  } else {
      const groupedMainProductValues = _.groupBy(
          buyingSessionProducts,
          (bsp: MainProduct) => bsp?.Original?.Original?.active?.Name ?? 'Undefined'
      )

      for (let value in groupedValues) {
          // Here value is of type MainProduct
      }
  }
})
```

You can extract common logic from both `for` loops int a separate function and invoke it if necessary